# Having trouble getting data across one component to another component?

Tags: angular, typescript, input

So I created a delete button for when an element is clicked and I want to be able to remove it. I am using an input decorator but its not receiving the data when I try to delete the button. I console log but it shows the array is empty. Its a little confusing explaining. Essentially its an example of a mini project dilemma I am working on. If someone could also explain a better way of input decorator and how to use it.

```
    ChildComponent:

    public valuesCheck: string [] = [];

    @Input() valuesFilter: string[] = [];
    public deleteClick(){
      let chipValue = string [] = [];
      this.valuesCheck = this.valuesFilter = chipValue;

      chipValue.splice(0,1);
    }

    Parent Component:
    public filters: CFilter[] | undefined;

    Parent HTML:
    <app-filter-chip  [valuesFiter] = "chipValue">
    <app-filter-chip>

    Child HTML:
    <div class="chip>
    <button class="closebtn" (click)="deleteClick()">
    <div>
```

Comment: Your setting `chipValue = []` and then you're removing the first item? Weird

Answer (score 0):

That's many problems:

1. Typo `valuesFilter` => `valuesFiter`
2. `chipValue` must be component's variable.

This is the example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v14-playground-ay5qvx?file=src/main.ts)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is you are allowing your child component to delete data from the parent component. That will happen using Output Emitter Approach (Please use that one).